# Can I call Win API functions from a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I have a WPF application that controls a robot arm. It's also a human-in-the-loop system. So I would like it to be as close to real time as possible. I am using a DispatcherTimer to generate a "tick" regularly to update the robot arm. Sort of like a poor mans Gameloop:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer Timer;
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send);
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTick);
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1.Read input devices
        //2.Do calculations
        //3.Move robot arm
    }
}
```

To be as near to real time as possible, this tick has to be generated as fast as possible, but because of limitations in Windows, the line...

```
Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
```

...has no real effect for values under ~15. It is limited by the fact that Windows schedules the "sleeps" and "wakes" of threads in 15.6ms intervals as explained nicely by [Bruce Dawson](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/) here.

But, as is also explained in this article, this default scheduling interval can be changed by calling [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) in timeapi.h

Can someone show or point me to an example how to call WinAPI functions, like `timeBeginPeriod(10);` from a WPF application?

Comment: Using P/Invoke? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke

Comment: Your Question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071359/how-to-set-timer-resolution-from-c-sharp-to-1-ms